# Calling behaviour of constructor confused me

Tags: angular, routes

I am studying parameterized routing in Angular in which I am stuck in constructor method behavior.

I have a employee details component like this

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-employeedetail',
  templateUrl: './employeedetail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employeedetail.component.css']
})
export class EmployeedetailComponent implements OnInit {
    eid : number;
    name : string;
    constructor(private rt : ActivatedRoute) {
      this.rt.params.subscribe(e=>{
        this.eid = e["id"];
        this.name = e["name"];
      })
      console.log("called detail constructor"+this.eid);
    }
      ngOnInit(){

      } 

}
```

employeedetail.component.html is like below

```
<p>employeedetail works!</p>
<span>ID of Employee is {{eid}} and name is {{name}}</span>

<a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" [routerLink]="['/employeedetail',102,'user2']">Next</a>
```

Step 1 :

I have a list employee window where I have list of employees like below.

```
<p>list-employee!</p>
<table>
    <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Mobile</th>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th>View</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>User1</td>
        <td>9696969696</td>
        <td>Pune</td>
        <td><a [routerLink]="['/employeedetail',101,'User1']">View</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>User2</td>
        <td>8686868686</td>
        <td>Pune</td>
        <td><a [routerLink]="['/employeedetail',102,'User2']">View</a></td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

When I am clicking in user 1 view link detail component is called so constructor method is also called and my eid and name is set with user 1 details

Step 2

I have added a next button link in detail page just to check constructor behavior on clicking next link my eid and name variable change with user 2 details but this should not happen as constructor is not called this time but still variables changes (`console.log("called detail constructor"+this.eid);` I have added this to check if it's called or not)

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because of the changes in the route parameter does not reconstruct the Component (i.e. `EmployeedetailComponent`). The magic is really happening because you have subscribed to an Observable when the very first time you landed on this page [i.e. component] -

```
this.rt.params.subscribe(e=>{
        this.eid = e["id"];
        this.name = e["name"];
      })
```

If in routing only the route parameters change then angular does not reconstruct the component instead it uses the same component instance which was created when app navigated to the requested route. Because you have subscribed to the `params` observable you are seeing that `eid` and `name` are changed.

On the same route if the route parameters change then angular router emits the new parameters value in `params` observable which will reevaluate the code on `params` subscribe [i.e. In your code `eid` and `name` will have new value].

Hope it answered your question and get rid of your confusion.

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is expected as you are receiving the values for the variables **eid** and **name** through the subscriber you added to the **params** observable attribute of the ActivatedRoute service you've injected.

At the first request for the first employee, angular creates the component and calls his constructor. After that, when you click on the **Next** button, angular will reuse the same component instance, but the params attribute of the ActivatedRoute service will emit a new event, with the new values for the new route